# Please help me this hard circle geometry question

Tags: circles, plane-geometry

Let $T_1$ be a circle with centre at the point $O$ and radius $R$. Two other circles $T_2$ and $T_3$ with centres at $O_2$ and $O_3$ respectively are tangent internally to $T_1$ and meet each other ($T_2$ and $T_3$) at the points $A$ and $B$. Find the sum of the radii of $T_2$ and $T_3$. $R_2$ + $R_3$, if $\angle OAB = \pi/2$.

[OP's thoughts, added by Brian Tung] I got $O_2AO_3B$ is a Kite. Also if extend $OA$ and intersects $T_3$ to point $W$ in $T_2$ for example, and extend $AO$ to $T_2$ then intersect $T_2$ to $V$, can get $O_2O_3$ equal to half of $WV$.  If I can approve $WV$ is paralleling to $O_2O_3$ or $OO_3$ is paralleling to $WB$, may get the result of $R_2 + R_3 = R$. Not sure if this is the right direction?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean $\angle AOB$ by any chance?

Comment: Please clarify me, what does "each other" mean? Touching of $T_1$ with $T_2$ and $T_3$ or the intersection $T_2$ and $T_3$?

Comment: can you please attach a picture of the problem with the points labelled? i cant identify the points.

Comment: A wild guess $r_2 + r_3 = r_1$.

Comment: @Samie I've added a picture to your question with what I believe is the correct interpretation of the problem. If it's not the correct interpretation, please ping me explaining what the correct interpretation is and I will change it. The edit should be up soon (it's in the edit review queue).

Comment: The picture is correct.

Comment: @Samie I've added the picture. Now how about you edit the question to add what you have tried already? It's not fair to us to simply give you the answer without any effort on your part, right?

Comment: Thanks, I got O2AO3B is a Kite. Also if extend OA and intersects T3 to point W in T2 for example, and extend AO to T2 then intersect T2 to V, can get O2O3 equal to half of WV.

Comment: If I can approve WV is paralleling to O2O3 or OO3 is paralleling to WB, may get the result of R2 + R3 = R. Not sure if this is the right direction?

Comment: @Samie  Please add your work *to the question*, not as comments. Then delete your last two comments (I'll delete mine as well) so that we save the comments area for more useful comments. Also, by adding your work to the question, I think its hold will be lifted.

Comment: @BrianTung Indeed. Also, the picture that I laboured for so long to create in order to help Samie has been removed as well. I thought that after I added the picture and Samie confirmed that it is the correct interpretation of the problem, all that was left for the hold to be lifted was for Samie to add his work to the question. Now this? I'm confused.

Comment: @BrianTung Thanks. I wasn't sure if it was ok to roll back so that's why I didn't do it myself. :) I also think that after Samie moves his thoughts to the question, we all should delete our comments about editing, etc and only leave behind comments that are actually pertinent to the question itself.

Comment: @BrianTung If you notice that the OP's account is no longer clickable, it should become clear that the account has been deleted (the user initiated this themself). I wouldn't expect any further responses from user261510 né Samie.

Comment: Thanks, @ArthurFischer.  Because the question looks interesting, I've restored the picture, added OP's thoughts, and reopened the question.  I've also removed my earlier comments.

Comment: @BrianTung FYI: I've posted a new question that's a cleaned up version of this one and am going to request this one to be deleted.

Comment: @BrianTung: I decided to close this as a duplicate of wltrup's (more responsible maintained) version. Because you put a lot of effort into restoring the question, I would like you to comment. If you object to me closing this, I understand, and will ask for others opinions (mods and regular users alike).